# My organization's projects are missing from Travis' "Repositories"

Tags: travis-ci

I have a personal Github profile ([@bvaughn](https://github.com/bvaughn/)) and I also belong to some organizations (e.g. [@forms-js](https://github.com/forms-js/)). One of the other *forms-js* developers recently tried to connect Travis to our [forms-js project](https://github.com/forms-js/forms-js/) but he hit a snag.

I'd like to help, but I'm unable to view the project in Travis. When I look at my Repositories, I only see the ones directly under my personal account (and not those under the shared forms-js organization).

I poked around the *forms-js* organization and made sure my membership was public - if that matters - but Travis doesn't seem to realize I'm associated with that organization.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I had to *explicitly* grant Travis access to my `forms-js` membership in the [Authorized applications](https://github.com/settings/applications) section of my Github profile.

After doing this, and logging out and back into Travis, the organization is showing.